# How do I access a VStack while UI testing my SwiftUI app

Tags: swiftui, xctest, xcuitest

I have a `VStack` with code relying on the `.onTapGesture` method. Something like this:

```swift
VStack {
    if imageShow {
        Image("image1")
    }
    else {
        Image("image2")
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
    imageShow.toggle()
}
```

I'd like to test this behavior within a UI Test using XCTest. The problem is, I don't know how to access the VStack in order to apply a `.tap()` to it. I can't seem to find the method attached to `app`. A button is found using `app.buttons[]` but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `app.VStack` or `app.HStack`.

Also, I've tried converting this code to wrap the `VStack` in a `Button`, but for some reason, this overlays my image, distorting the preferred behavior.

Updating with full `VStack` code snippet that I am working with:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    ZStack {
        if self.create_event_vm.everyone_toggle == true {
            Image("loginBackground")
                .resizable()
                .accessibility(identifier: "everyone_toggle_background")
            }
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Visible to everyone on Hithr")
                    .kerning(0.8)
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Medium", size: 18)                                          .foregroundColor(self.create_event_vm.everyone_toggle ? Color.white : Color.black)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)

                    Text("Public event")
                        .kerning(0.5)
                        .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Light", size: 16)
                                    .foregroundColor(self.create_event_vm.everyone_toggle ? Color.white : Color.black)
                        .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 74)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.create_event_vm.everyone_toggle.toggle()
        }
        .accessibility(identifier: "public_event_toggle")
        .accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following approach

```
VStack {
    if imageShow {
        Image("image1")
    }
    else {
        Image("image2")
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
    imageShow.toggle()
}
.accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)
.accessibility(identifier: "customButton")
```

and test

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.buttons["customButton"].exists)
```

Comment: It's giving me the following error: `Failed to get matching snapshot: Multiple matching elements found for`. It looks like it's attaching itself to every `Text()` view within the VStack.

Comment: You can use app.buttons["something"].firstMatch to get around the Multiple matching elements found error.

Comment: There is a better way, see my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to create an un-styled **GroupBox** to "wrap" any content inside.
After that we can assign an **accessibilityIdentifier** to it.
It doesn't disrupt the screen readers or change the layout.

**Code:**

```swift
/// Groupbox "no-op" container style without label
/// to combine the elements for accessibilityId
struct ContainerGroupBoxStyle: GroupBoxStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.content
    }
}

extension GroupBoxStyle where Self == ContainerGroupBoxStyle {
    static var contain: Self { Self() }
}

extension View {
    /// This method wraps the view inside a GroupBox
    /// and adds accessibilityIdentifier to it
    func groupBoxAccessibilityIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> some View {
        GroupBox {
            self
        }
        .groupBoxStyle(.contain)
        .accessibilityIdentifier(identifier)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person")
            TextField("Name", text: .constant("Name"))
        }
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Stack Tap")
        }
        .groupBoxAccessibilityIdentifier("NAME_TEXTFIELD")
    }
}
```

**Locating in XCTest:**

```swift
app.descendants(matching: .any)["NAME_TEXTFIELD"]
// OR
app.otherElements["NAME_TEXTFIELD"]
```

Note: `GroupBox` is unavailable in tvOS and watchOS.

Comment: how do you access it from a UI test? with `groups`, `otherElements` or something else? also note: group box is unavailable in tvOS and watchOS

Comment: @freya Ty for your input, I've updated my answer. You can use `.any` match or `otherElements`, yup. I've checked that it works in Accessibility Inspector + verified with my Appium colleague that he is happy with the results. Never tried it in `XCTest` :)

Answer (score 1):

I find that `otherElements["x"]` doesn't work for ZStack, VStack or HStack. Instead I identify something else, like a Text, and try to get using `staticTexts["x"]`.