# SwiftUI accessibilityIdentifier is not working for UI Tests

Tags: macos, swiftui, accessibility, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to use Xcode UI Tests with a SwiftUI macOS app. Accessibility identifiers don't seem to be working.

For example, the following code shows a UI Test, a debugger command to print the element tree, and the code for the app. The element tree does not show the accessibility identifiers that were set in the code. In addition, the entire `NSViewRepresentable` is missing, but I'll save that for another question.

Notice that `Button1`, `FirstView`, `AppKitView` and `VStack1` are all missing from the element tree. The ID `MyWindow` does make it into the tree.

How do we set accessibility IDs on SwiftUI views so we can refer to them in UI Tests?

(I'm using Xcode 13.4.1, macOS 12.4)

```swift
func testExample() throws {
    // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    let window = app.windows.element(boundBy: 0)
    print("stop here.") // Set a break point here to look at stuff
}
```

```
(lldb) po print(window.debugDescription)
    [...]
Attributes: Window (Main), 0x7fd7f09087b0, {{270.0, 132.0}, {250.0, 278.0}}, identifier: 'MyWinID-AppWindow-1', title: 'Title', Keyboard Focused, Disabled
Element subtree:
 →Window (Main), 0x7fd7f09087b0, {{270.0, 132.0}, {250.0, 278.0}}, identifier: 'MyWinID-AppWindow-1', title: 'Title', Keyboard Focused, Disabled
    StaticText, 0x7fd7f09088e0, {{358.8, 160.0}, {72.5, 16.0}}, identifier: 'MyWindow', value: SwiftUI Text
    Button, 0x7fd7f0908a10, {{352.5, 186.0}, {85.5, 20.0}}, identifier: 'MyWindow', title: 'Test Button'
    Button, 0x7fd7f0908de0, {{277.0, 138.0}, {14.0, 16.0}}, identifier: '_XCUI:CloseWindow'
    Button, 0x7fd7f0908f10, {{317.0, 138.0}, {14.0, 16.0}}, identifier: '_XCUI:FullScreenWindow'
    Button, 0x7fd7f0909040, {{297.0, 138.0}, {14.0, 16.0}}, identifier: '_XCUI:MinimizeWindow'
    StaticText, 0x7fd7f0908b40, {{378.0, 137.0}, {33.0, 16.0}}, value: Title
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SwiftUI Text").accessibilityIdentifier("FirstView")
            Button("Test Button") {
                print("clicked")
            }.accessibilityIdentifier("Button1")
            AppKitView().accessibilityIdentifier("AppKitView")
        }.accessibilityIdentifier("VStack1")
    }
}

struct AppKitView: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = AppKitViewImpl
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AppKitViewImpl {
        let v = AppKitViewImpl()
        return v
    }
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AppKitViewImpl, context: Context) {
        
    }
}

@main
struct DemoUITestsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Title", id: "MyWinID") {
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                .accessibilityIdentifier("MyWindow")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Googling around, it appears accessibility IDs and VStacks do not play well together. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671189 suggests a fix, but warns of a memory leak. Can you also try defining the contained elements outside of the VStack?

Comment: HStack didn't work either. Without those two, I'm not sure how to layout anything in SwiftUI. Using `accessibilityElement(...)`  (from the link) does help, but I haven't looked for the memory leak yet. Since I only want to use this for testing, that might be good enough for my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access a VStack while UI testing my SwiftUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392499/how-do-i-access-a-vstack-while-ui-testing-my-swiftui-app)

Answer (score 0):

In order to utilize accessibility identifiers in SwiftUI previews for macOS apps, you need to specify the environment for accessibility. This can be achieved by adding `.environment(.accessibilityEnabled, true)` to the struct.