# Cannot assign accessibilityIdentifier to a SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, uiaccessibility, uitest

**Setup:**

I have a SwiftUI `Map` with some custom `annotationItems`.
I want to check the numbers of `annotationItems` on the map in UITests.
Thus, I am trying to assign to each `annotationItem` an `accessibilityIdentifier`, so that I can query for them.
There are 2 `MapAnnotation` views with a pin image instantiated as:

```
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            annotationItems: annotations) { annotation in
        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                AnnotationView(annotation: annotation,
                                             region: region, 
                                             mapViewModel: mapViewModel, 
                                             annotationDragged: $annotationDragged)
                .accessibilityIdentifier(kLocationPin)
            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        }
```

**Problem:**

In my test method, I query for the map annotations.
Since map annotations are handled in UITests as `otherElements` of the app, I am using:

```
let actualPinsShown = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: kLocationPin)
```

However, this query does not find any map annotation.
If I issue in the debugger the following command

```
(lldb) po app.otherElements
```

a lot of `otherElements` are printed, among them

```
  Other, 0x128d19c80, {{30.3, 273.0}, {30.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Stecknadel'
  Other, 0x128d1c300, {{332.3, 576.0}, {30.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Stecknadel'
```

Here, the `label` `Stecknadel` (the German word for pin) obviously indicates the 2 `MapAnnotation` views that display a pin.
However, the `accessibilityIdentifier` is not set, and thus they cannot be found by the UITest.

**Questions:**

Why is the `accessibilityIdentifier` not set?
Is something wrong with my code?
If so, how to do it right? If not, is there a workaround?

**PS:**
It seems that others have similar problems, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73014842/1987726). I am working with Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18). Maybe this an unfixed bug.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, maybe by a workaround:

My `AnnotationView` is essentially the following (unimportant code left out):

```
struct AnnotationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Image("PinRed")
        }
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
}
```

In the code presented in my question, I tried to set the `accessibilityIdentifier` for an `AnnotationView` as

```
AnnotationView(annotation: annotation,
               region: region, 
               mapViewModel: mapViewModel, 
               annotationDragged: $annotationDragged)
.accessibilityIdentifier(kLocationPin)
```

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityidentifier(_:)) say: `accessibilityIdentifier(_:)` *Uses the string you specify to identify the view.*
I therefore assumed that my `AnnotationView` will get this identifier. **But this is not true.**

If I query in the debugger for images using `app.images.matching(identifier: kLocationPin)`, I get

```
↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"LocationPin" IN identifiers'
  Output: {
    Image, 0x14725f2c0, {{30.3, 273.0}, {30.0, 30.0}}, identifier: 'LocationPin', label: 'PinRed'
    Image, 0x147260940, {{332.3, 576.0}, {30.0, 30.0}}, identifier: 'LocationPin', label: 'PinRed'
  }
```

This shows that the `accessibilityIdentifier` is not attached to the `AnnotationView`, but to the image inside.
I consider this as a SwiftUI bug, because the identifier identifies not the View it was attached to, but a View inside.